# Where did the in-air pointing and pinching gestures come from for AR and VR?

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'm seeing a lot of tech demos lately that feature the user of an AR or VR system using a pinch in air or point in air gesture. I'm wondering where this convention came from. For touchscreen gestures, I know microsoft did a bunch of research in the early 2000s to create a taxonomy, but I haven't found anything for AR / VR. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like interactions from touch screen which users are used to. Could you link to some video that shows this gestures in-action?

Comment: At a guess I'd say they were probably based on touching or grabbing things within the three dimensional space - I don't know where you'd look for evidence though.

Comment: AR and VR is still very much in its infancy, and there hasn't been enough time for standards and conventions to bubble up, so I really doubt you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Does anyone else find this weird? Before multitouch even hit the market in a big way, we had lots of data and research on intuitive multitouch gestures, but it doesn't seem exist for VR / AR applications...

Answer (score 1):

Qualcomm did a lot of research into gestures for their AR platform (that they have since sold off). This included pinch gestures. If i remember correctly it was because their system could recognise digits plus it was to be used infront of a mobile phone camera.

Their research was augmented by knowledge shared from Microsoft Research.

Comment: Brilliant! I found 1 whitepaper from Qualcomm on it. Any articles or other publications you know of?